# Add more info to entityreference autocomplete widgets

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using a simple entityreference field with "autocomplete" widget on a content type.

When I start to search something, the autocomplete function returns me only the title of the node. Is there a way to add some information? I would like to add created time, or nid.

I tried to create an "entityreference" view as widget, but It useful only to select contents with filter or others configurations.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at the Entity Browser module: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser

Or Content Browser, which is specifically designed for nodes:
https://www.drupal.org/project/content_browser

I haven't used it yet, but it's on my want-to-learn list. I think it does what you want.